# how can i transfer old format to now json format with jolt?

Tags: json, jolt

i have a JSON array,and want transfer it to new one;
this is the JSON value that want to get!

```json
{
  "ZJ_S0BCT01CE200" : 0.06411704421043396,
  "N1TC_W_PEC" : 10
}
```

and this is my input JSON;

```json
[
  {
    "code": "ZJ_S0BCT01CE200",
    "data": [
      {
        "time": 1627286919345,
        "value": 0.06411704421043396
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "code": "N1TC_W_PEC",
    "data": [
      {
        "time": 1627286919345,
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

it toke almost 6 hours (灬ꈍ ꈍ灬)
and only get this output below. How can i add a code as a key in new JSON?

```json
{
  "data": {
    "data-0": {
      "code": "Container-16-LC_Summary_Sys_AC_bus_frequency",
      "value": 50.09
    },
    "data-1": {
      "code": "Container-16-LC_Summary_PCS_Total_PCS_active_power",
      "value": 0
    }
  }
}
```

my dsl is blow:

```json
{
  "*": {
    "code": "data.data-&(1,0).code",
    "data": {
      "*": {
        "value": "data.&(2,0)-&(3,0).value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply such a **shift** transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "value": "@(3,code)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to cross over opening curly braces triple up to reach the level of the value of `code` while roaming(`"data": {"*":...`) within the elements of the `data` list(*array*)

Comment: thanks a lot! ^_^ .get a new usage of ‘@‘ 。

Comment: you're welcome @PaulZhu , have a nice study!